# Python - Pillow thumbnail creation error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When I try to create thumbnail from any images, this error occurred:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Command:

```
./manage.py shell
from PIL import Image
i = Image.open('1.jpg')
i.thumbnail(200)
```

error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-3e0cd0330e45> in <module>()
----> 1 i.thumbnail(200)

/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.pyc
in thumbnail(self, size, resample)
   1828         # preserve aspect ratio
   1829         x, y = self.size
-> 1830         if x > size[0]:
   1831             y = int(max(y * size[0] / x, 1))
   1832             x = int(size[0])

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Somewhere I read something about libjpeg package, but I got this error for all type files`(gif,png,...)`.

I use archlinux:

```
$ uname -a
Linux chalist 4.9.11-1-ARCH # 1 SMP PREEMPT 
Sun Feb 19 13:45:52 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size needs to be in the form of a tuple, such as `(200, 200)`. So your new code would be:

```
from PIL import Image
i = Image.open('1.jpg')
i.thumbnail((200, 200))
```

Here's a link to the reference webpage: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#create-thumbnails

Comment: :/ my mistake, tnx